# How to plot the distribution between 2 variables with Plotly Express (Python)?

Tags: python, plot, plotly

I have a dataframe, which looks like this and contains around 20.000 rows.

```
print(df)
>>>>
CUSTOMER_INCOME   MARITAL_STATUS
   50000          Relationship
   65000          Single
   17000          Single
   120000         Relationship
   42000          Relationship
   56000          Single
```

(*MARITAL_STATUS has only these 2 variables: Relationship and Single)

I am trying to use plotly in order visualize the distribution of the 'Customer Income' according to their 'Marital_Status'.

The following code delivers this plot, but it doesn't look right.

```
px.scatter(df, x = 'Marital_Status', y = "Customer_Income")
```

[image]

How can I plot the distribution of the 'Customer Income' according to their 'Marital_Status' using plotly in a more reasonable way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to use the color option in using px.histogram. I believe this solves your problem:

```
fig = px.histogram(df, x="CUSTOMER_INCOME",color="MARITAL_STATUS",barmode="overlay")
```

Do note that this won't get you distributions (distributions sum to 1), but it will give you a histogram. If you do want that, consider looking at https://plotly.com/python-api-reference/generated/plotly.express.histogram.html to find if the histnorm option is of any use to you.

Comment: Thank you very much! This definitely solves my problem. Pure and simple. However, thanks to the documentation you provided, I found out that "relative" or "group" instead of "overlay" for 'barmode=' visualizes the differences between Single and Relationship much better. "Overlay" eclipses the smaller values (mostly for Single) while relative allows to see both Relationship and Single. Thanks again. Issue solved.

Comment: Perfect, good to hear you found a better option!